# Passing data from a page to an external link

Tags: plugins

I am creating an event booking site on Wordpress:

1. User clicks on a Book Now on a event page on WP website.
2. He lands on external page where he can see:

   - Title of event(prefilled and uneditable),
   - Event id (hidden) (prefilled),
   - Groupsize,
   - Currency preselected by default
3. Once he clicks on Pay on this page, It will fetch the price of the event from DB and then multiply with 5 and the make a call to an external page.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have wordpress.com & wordpress.org tagged.  Which are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want and i don't know why cannot comment...

Anyways when the user click over pay, make a request and retrieve from DB the cost then just make a redirect with your language to other page.